# Getting line FID from polygon ITopologyGraph

Tags: arcobjects, esri-geodatabase, topology, vba

I want to export polygon Arc list to txt file for that

I created topologygraph for personal geodatabase feature class (polygon)
using  ITopologyGraph::build.

I got polygon FIDs but I am not getting IDs for individual edges of polygons.

Comment: Can you say what software or programming language you want to do this in? It sounds like an adjacency matrix might help, but I don't fully understand the problem.

Comment: questions sounds strangely like http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5365/getting-line-fid-from-polygon-topologygraph/5377#5377 from user with strangely similar handle 'srikanthrao'

Answer (score 3):

why not just run the gp PolygonToLine tool ? (ArcINFO only)

it takes polygon input, writes out a line feature class with LEFT/RIGHT polygon ID.

Answer (score 1):

The individual [edges](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ITopologyEdge_Interface/0025000009nw000000/) in a topology based solely on a polygon featureclass don't have ID's.  You would need to write out the geometry of the edges to a polyline featureclass, then use their OID's (as suggested by gotchula).